# React-slick not rendering slides

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I'm using a plugin called react-slick for a carousel. I have tried to implement a carousel which has dynamic slides, however when it renders it doesn't seem to initialise each of the slides. Is it because the slider has initialised before the children?

this.extractData basically gets json object

```
createCarousel = () => {
    let data = this.extractData();
    const settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    };
    return(
        <Slider {...settings}>
            {data.map(function(object, i){
                return <testLayout data={object} key={i} />;
            })}
        </Slider>
    );
};

render() {

    return (
        <div className="difference">
            {this.createCarousel()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

testLayout

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class testLayout extends Component {

render() {
    let item = this.props.data.items;
    return (
        <div className="slide">
            <img src={item.imgUrl} alt=""/>
            <p>{item.text}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default testLayout;
```

any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

UPDATE - found fix https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/328

Comment: What is `testLayout ` and what is the code of the `data`?

Comment: testLayout is a component that renders an image and text. data prop is the content of the component

Comment: I know that. Add the code of both of them.

Comment: Add your update as an answer. It's perfectly fine to answer on your own question. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).